# react-hook-form no me funciona el ref={

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo a validar formularios con react-hook-form pero cuando pongo el `ref={` para hacer la validacion se me pone todo el documento blanco y no sale nada. El `required` y `minLength` directamente no me los colorea.

```
*import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
const HookFormulario = () => {
    const {register, errors, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data,e)=>{
        console.log(data)
    }
    return ( 
        <>
            <h1>Creando un formulario con React Hook Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    name='titulo'
                    placeholder='Ingrese un titulo'
                    className='form-control my-2'
                    ref={
                        register({
                            required: {value: true, message: 'Pone al menos una letra peton'},
                            minLength:{value: 5, message: 'Minimo 5 letras pajero'}
                        })
                    }
                />
                {   errors.titulo &&
                    <span className='text-danger text-small d-block mb-2'>
                        {errors.titulo.message}
                    </span>}*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si checas la documentación de [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started). La manera en la que ellos recomiendan registrar un input es haciendo **spread** del `register`. De la siguiente manera:

```
<input
    name='titulo'
    placeholder='Ingrese un titulo'
    className='form-control my-2'
    {...register('titulo', {
    required: 'Este espacio es requerido.'
    minLength: { value: 5, message: 'Al menos 5 letras.' }
     })}/>
```

El `register` toma dos argumentos: el nombre (un string) por el cual estás registrando el input y las opciones (un objeto) para ese input.

Adicional a eso, hay dos cosas que debes tener en cuenta:

1.Los errores los obtienes del `formState`:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
```

2.A la hora de ejecutar el `handleSubmit` lo debes ejecutar así:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```